# Standard deviation from center of mass along Numpy array axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, standard-deviation, weighted-average

I am trying to find a well-performing way to calculate the standard deviation from the center of mass/gravity along an axis of a Numpy array.

In formula this is (sorry for the misalignment):

[image]

The best I could come up with is this:

```
def weighted_com(A, axis, weights):
    average = np.average(A, axis=axis, weights=weights)
    return average * weights.sum() / A.sum(axis=axis).astype(float)

def weighted_std(A, axis):
    weights = np.arange(A.shape[axis])
    w1com2 = weighted_com(A, axis, weights)**2
    w2com1 = weighted_com(A, axis, weights**2)
    return np.sqrt(w2com1 - w1com2)
```

In `weighted_com`, I need to correct the normalization from sum of weights to sum of values (which is an ugly workaround, I guess). `weighted_std` is probably fine.

To avoid the XY problem, I still ask for what I actually want, (a better `weighted_std`) instead of a better version of my `weighted_com`.

The `.astype(float)` is a safety measure as I'll apply this to histograms containing ints, which caused problems due to integer division when not in Python 3 or when `from __future__ import division` is not active.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take the mean, variance and standard deviation of the vector `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]` — where `n` is the dimension of the input matrix `A` along the axis of interest —, with weights given by the matrix `A` itself.

For concreteness, say you want to consider these center-of-mass statistics along the vertical axis (`axis=0`) — this is what corresponds to the formulas you wrote. For a fixed column `j`, you would do

```
n = A.shape[0]
r = np.arange(1, n+1)
mu = np.average(r, weights=A[:,j])
var = np.average(r**2, weights=A[:,j]) - mu**2
std = np.sqrt(var)
```

In order to put all of the computations for the different columns together, you have to stack together a bunch of copies of `r` (one per column) to form a matrix (that I have called `R` in the code below). With a bit of care, you can make things work for both `axis=0` and `axis=1`.

```
import numpy as np

def com_stats(A, axis=0):
    A = A.astype(float)    # if you are worried about int vs. float
    n = A.shape[axis]
    m = A.shape[(axis-1)%2]
    r = np.arange(1, n+1)
    R = np.vstack([r] * m)
    if axis == 0:
        R = R.T

    mu = np.average(R, axis=axis, weights=A)
    var = np.average(R**2, axis=axis, weights=A) - mu**2
    std = np.sqrt(var)
    return mu, var, std
```

For example,

```
A = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
print(A)

# [[1 1 0]
#  [1 2 1]
#  [1 1 1]]

print(com_stats(A))

# (array([ 2. ,  2. ,  2.5]),                   # centre-of-mass mean by column
#  array([ 0.66666667,  0.5       ,  0.25  ]),  # centre-of-mass variance by column
#  array([ 0.81649658,  0.70710678,  0.5   ]))  # centre-of-mass std by column
```

EDIT:

One can avoid creating in-memory copies of `r` to build `R` by using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`: swap the line

```
R = np.vstack([r] * m)
```

above with

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
R = as_strided(r, strides=(0, r.itemsize), shape=(m, n))
```

The resulting `R` is a (strided) `ndarray` whose underlying array is the same as `r`'s — absolutely no copying of any values occurs.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

FMT = '''\
Shape: {}
Strides: {}
Position in memory: {}
Size in memory (bytes): {}
'''

def find_base_nbytes(obj):
    if obj.base is not None:
        return find_base_nbytes(obj.base)
    return obj.nbytes

def stats(obj):
    return FMT.format(obj.shape,
                      obj.strides,
                      obj.__array_interface__['data'][0],
                      find_base_nbytes(obj))

n=10
m=1000
r = np.arange(1, n+1)
R = np.vstack([r] * m)
S = as_strided(r, strides=(0, r.itemsize), shape=(m, n))

print(stats(r))
print(stats(R))
print(stats(S))
```

Output:

```
Shape: (10,)
Strides: (8,)
Position in memory: 4299744576
Size in memory (bytes): 80

Shape: (1000, 10)
Strides: (80, 8)
Position in memory: 4304464384
Size in memory (bytes): 80000

Shape: (1000, 10)
Strides: (0, 8)
Position in memory: 4299744576
Size in memory (bytes): 80
```

Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637875/size-of-numpy-strided-array-broadcast-array-in-memory/34638891#34638891) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264838/how-to-get-the-memory-address-of-a-numpy-array-for-c/11266170#11266170) for explanations on how to get the memory address and size of the underlying array of a strided `ndarray`.

Comment: I see. It tried something like this, before I came up with the solution in my question... However, I was worried about creating the (potentially huge) `R` matrix. As `R` is anyway containing only copies of `r`, can we get rid of the copying?

Comment: Oh, that's a pretty nice trick. Memory-wise, I'd guess we are on par now. Do you see a potential difference still? Seem, we should profile our solutions for performance ...