# Memory usage of numpy views

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba, space-complexity

Do numpy views store pointers or float objects?

I am trying to use numpy sliding view to perform something without pandas

```
arr =np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
    (np.arange(510)), (50), axis=0
)
```

This `arr` is a read-only object, but is it using the same amount of memory as an ndarray?
Apparently `.nbytes` returns the same, but

```
from sys import getsizeof
getsizeof(arr)
# Returns 128
getsizeof(arr.copy())
# Returns 184528
```

What is happening here?

=======================Edit=======================

- related question: [How much memory is used by the underlying buffer of a broadcasted numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112994/how-much-memory-is-used-by-the-underlying-buffer-of-a-broadcasted-numpy-array)
- numpy docs: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

@juanpa has pointed out views share the same underlying buffer.

AFAI understand, it means views are pass-by-reference

Comment: views share the *same underlying buffer*. Note, `arr` **is** a `numpy.ndarray`. It just shares it's buffer with another array (the one you passed to `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`)

Comment: That small `getsizeof` value means the `view` does not own its databuffer.  It's using/referencing the buffer created by the `arange`.